# When a RAID0 fails, can you still see all the file/folder names?

Tags: raid, raid-0

When a RAID0 fails, can you still see all the file/folder names?

I'm considering making a RAID0 NAS but am unsure how failure occurs.

It's not the data I am concerned about losing but the reference to *what* data was lost (names). I have backups and can recover what might get lost.

Comment: The best way to recover data when a RAID0 array fails is to restore from backups. Backups are particularly important when using RAID0. Recovery of data from RAID0 is difficult under the best of circumstances and should only be considered as an emergency measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. Raid 0 stripes data across two drives - this increases speed (since you're roughly splitting disk accesses across two drives), and in a sense lets you use all of the capacity of the two disks as one volume, but you are *completely* hosed if one drive dies and pieces of your data are just gone.

Raid 0 *isn't* designed for resiliency, its designed for performance.

Comment: Okay. Wasn't sure if maybe the names/properties were indexed somewhere in RAID's.

Comment: No, they're not. A RAID volume presents an array of numbered blocks to the host OS, just like a non-RAID volume does. Neither has any clue about file systems.